# Where is the key?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

```
resource "google_service_account" "myaccount" {
  account_id = "dev-foo-account"
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "mykey" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.myaccount.name
}

data "google_service_account_key" "mykey" {
  name            = google_service_account_key.mykey.name
  public_key_type = "TYPE_X509_PEM_FILE"
}
```

If I create a Service Account and a key like this - how do I obtain the key afterwards?

`terraform output` yields:

```
$ terraform output -json google_service_account_key
The output variable requested could not be found in the state
file. If you recently added this to your configuration, be
sure to run `terraform apply`, since the state won't be updated
with new output variables until that command is run.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to put that variable as an output if you want to use it after apply the plan:

```
output "my_private_key" {
  value = data.google_service_account_key.mykey.private_key
}
```

To output the value of "my_private_key":

```
$ terraform output my_private_key
```

To obtain the credentials as a JSON which can later be used for authentication:

```
$ terraform output -raw key | base64 -d -
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow. Technically speaking, though, what I need is the private key, of course. I assume it's accessable by .private_key.

Comment: Sorry! my bad. I assumed that you wanted to extract the public key. I've edited my answer accordingly to extract the private key. Thanks